# UIButton UIControlDefault title value

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

Need to check whether `IBOutLet UIButton *button` has no text written on it.
What to code?

```
NSLog(@"%@", [button titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]);   //it gives (null)
```

HOw should I write the decision statement?

Comment: An UIButton item has the property `titleLabel`. TitleLabel inherits from UILabel. You can acces to the text of an UILabel with its property `text`so I guess you can do what you want with `button.titleLabel.text`and check if the string is null or not with `isEqualToString`.

Comment: tried it that buddy, doesn't work. What is the equal value in objective c while comparing it to GDB (null).
`nil` `NULL` `NIL` `null` ??

Comment: I don't really know but you can try with `[NSNull null]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better to check the length of the `button.labelTitle.text`.

Thanks for the answers guys.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set the title for `UIControlState` like this:

```
[button setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Otherwise, everything should work correctly.

**UPDATE**

To check out if it has no text, use this :

```
if (![menuItemButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]) {
    NSLog(@"YES, no text.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"no, there is text.");
}
```

Comment: if you find my answer helpful, don't forget to mark it as the correct answer and thump-up the answer.

Comment: it always return YES, whether UIButton contain text or not!